# How would I sort and group this and loop over it with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

Ok so i have a pages table with all the static with this schema

```
create_table "pages", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "html"
  t.string   "url"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.boolean  "is_home"
  t.integer  "parent_id",  :default => 0, :null => false
  t.string   "nav"
end
```

A page can have another page as its parent. The idea is that I want the user to have complete control of the navigation and the pages. So my question what is the best way to group these pages so in the html i can loop over all the pages and their subpages

Here is what i have so far

```
grouped_pages = Page.where(:is_home => 0).group_by(&:nav).each do |key, group|
 group.sort_by(&:parent_id)
end
```

I was hoping to group them in some array and or hash combination with another layer for ever page that has a parent_id of another page

the page structure can look like this

```
Page1
  Page3
    Page7
  Page4
  Page5
Page2
  Page5
  Page6
```

Any ideas of the best way to sort and loop over to print out the uls for the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow arbitrarily nested tree levels, the easiest solution is a recursive algorithm. For example (uses `parent_id = NULL`, not 0, for the page root):

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => :Page
  has_many :children, :class_name => :Page, :foreign_key => :parent_id 

  def self.root
    where(:parent => nil).first
  end

  def tree
    [self, children.map(&:tree)]
  end
end

Page.root.tree 
#=> returns the structure in pairs [page, children]
```

From this you can do whatever you need. For exemple, to set a sort criterion, just add an options argument to `tree` and use it to scope `children`.

Note that to render a tree structure you also need a recursive helper to perform the task. In fact probably you don't need this `tree` method, just a recursive helper that calls `children`, but the idea is the same.

As Mark points out, there are gems to implement AR trees, for example [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree).

Comment: @MarkThomas: Added to the answer. But you'll agree every programmer should know how to implement a basic tree.

Answer (score 1):

With a gem like [closure tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) you can have the same basic tree behavior, plus all the following:

- a nested hash with all the hierarchy
- the list of all ancestors of a node
- all descendants of a node
- all the siblings of a node

and many others, implemented so to execute only one query.

(See http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/tags/closure-tree for reasons behind such a tree.)